# how to manipulate value in spinner android

Tags: android, android-spinner

i have a spinner with 4 value

```
String[] petak = { "Petak 1", "Petak 2", "Petak 3", "Petak 4" };
```

[image: Image 1]

**First** i choose the value "Petak 1"

then i choose "foto dan save" to next step

and the value now is

[image: Image 2]

because value "Petak 1" is already choosen before, so the value "Petak 1" is dissapear.

now i choose "foto dan save" again

and the value is

[image: Image 3]

because value "Petak 1" and "Petak 2" is already choosen before, so the value "Petak 1" and "Petak 2" is dissapear.

The question is how to manipulate value spinner when i choose the value **Random** , Example : i choose "Petak 2" First ? so the value is show "Petak 1", "Petak 3", "Petak 4"

here is my code

```
            View spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namapetak);
            String spinnerPetak=((Spinner) spinner1).getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (spinnerPetak == "Petak 1"){
                String[] petak1 = { "Petak 2", "Petak 3", "Petak 4" };
                // buat spinner manual manufaktur
                Spinner spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namapetak);
                //spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, petak1);
                aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spin3.setAdapter(aa);
                //update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);

                spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namapetak);
                spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(CPupukApp.this, "Anda Memilih: " + manufaktur[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                    });
                View b = findViewById(R.id.btnPupukQuit);
                b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                onBackPressed();
                onAttachedToWindow();

            }

            if (spinnerPetak == "Petak 2"){
                String[] petak1 = { "Petak 3", "Petak 4" };
                // buat spinner manual manufaktur
                Spinner spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namapetak);
                //spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, petak1);
                aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spin3.setAdapter(aa);
                //update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);

                spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namapetak);
                spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(CPupukApp.this, "Anda Memilih: " + manufaktur[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                    });
                View b = findViewById(R.id.btnPupukQuit);
                b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                onBackPressed();
                onAttachedToWindow();

            }

            if (spinnerPetak == "Petak 3"){
                String[] petak1 = { "Petak 4" };
                // buat spinner manual manufaktur
                Spinner spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namapetak);
                //spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, petak1);
                aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spin3.setAdapter(aa);
                //update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);

                spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namapetak);
                spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(CPupukApp.this, "Anda Memilih: " + manufaktur[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                    });
                View b = findViewById(R.id.btnPupukQuit);
                b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                onBackPressed();
                onAttachedToWindow();

            }
```

Anyone help me?

**EDIT**

this code work when i put this on button onClick "Foto dan Save", but error when i put to onActivityResult , line `switch (v.getId())` can `switch` add in onActivityResult?

```
String myData = toList.getSelectedItem().toString();
              int position = dataAdapter.getPosition(myData);

              switch (View.getId()) {



              case R.id.btnPetakFoto:

               if(position >= 0){
                dataAdapter.remove(myData);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
               else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), myData + " not in Spinner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
               // More buttons go here (if any) ...

              }

            View b = findViewById(R.id.btnPupukQuit);
            b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            onBackPressed();
            onAttachedToWindow();
```

Comment: i think easy way is use ArrayList instead of Array and use `ArrayList.remove(<Selected Item index in Spinner>)` to first remove selected item from ArrayList then set it back as datasource for Spinner

Comment: Your latest edit would be better suited as a separate question as you'd be able to have a cleaner question with your current code and be able to pinpoint your exact problem easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, what you want to be doing is using an `ArrayList` to hold your underlying data, and then updating this when you click on your *Foto dan Save* button.

A small example of how you would do this is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
Spinner spinner1;
ArrayList<String> petak;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    petak = new ArrayList<String>();
    petak.add("Petak 1");
    petak.add("Petak 2");
    petak.add("Petak 3");
    petak.add("Petak 4");

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_petak);
    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, petak);

    spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    Button foto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.foto);
    foto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            petak.remove(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
            spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

}
```

This is self-contained code, so you can copy this into a new project and it will work as intended, or you can take the important parts and apply them to your code.

Basically what we're doing is creating a new `ArrayList` and adding your four *Petak* values to it. We then create a new `SpinnerAdapter`, giving it your `ArrayList` as a reference.

When the user clicks on the *foto* button, we remove the selected item `String` from the underlying `ArrayList` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on our `SpinnerAdapter` in order to update the list of items displayed.

Comment: That would really be better suited as a separate question, you'd be able to have a cleaner question with your current code and be able to pinpoint your exact problem easier

Answer (score 2):

Use ArrayList to solve your problem, you should also consider using switch instead of a bunch of if's.

Good Luck